# Как из списка убрать пустые и содержащие только пробел элементы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть список:

```
['', 'apple', '', ' ', 'banana', '', ' ', 'pine', '', ' ', 'price', '', ' ']
```

Kак мне убрать `''` и `' '` из списка?

Comment: @0xdb как-бы '  ' - это не пустой элемент.

Comment: @strawdog Так? Надо же обобщать, с пробелом не пустые, но почти пустые. А написать "почти пустые" - уж точно никто не поймёт.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

в функциональном стиле:

```
res = list(filter(len, map(str.strip, lst)))

print(res)
>>> ['apple', 'banana', 'pine', 'price']
```

Answer (score 6):

```
lst = ['', 'apple', '', ' ', 'banana', '', ' ', 'pine', '', ' ', 'price', '', ' ']
res = [x for x in lst if len(x.strip())]
print(res)
```

> ['apple', 'banana', 'pine', 'price']

Answer (score 1):

```
[*res] = filter(bool, map(str.lstrip, lst))
```